# Razor Page と MVC のメリット・デメリット

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

ASP.NET Core には
・Razor Pagesアプリケーション
・MVCアプリケーション
の２種類がありますが、それぞれどのように使い分ければよいのでしょうか？
各アプリケーションのメリット・デメリットを教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

.NETでMVC、.NET CoreでRazor Pageを作成しました。私見ですが使い分けという観点では、どちらでも構わないと思います。
MVCにおいてはViewとModelは独立した存在ですが、Viewに検索ボックスなどを入れると、どうしてもViewだけに関連したModelが欲しくなります。いわゆるViewModelというやつですが、これと、DnContextで使うModelとの違いをルール化しないと面倒です。
Razor Pageには、Page事体がPageModelの派生クラスをもっていますので、ModelフォルダにはDbContextで使うModelしか無くなって見栄え良いです。ですから自分はこうしようと思ってます。

- 一から作成する場合は、Razor Page
- 現在のMVCプロジェクトを引き継ぐならMVC

ご参考になれば。